# C# skip csv coulmns while importing to data table

Tags: c#, datatable

in the below mentioned code i am trying to import a large CSV file to datatable adding first row as header. while importing i am skipping certain header's if it contains certain text strings.
i want to skip row value if the header is missing.Please help.
here is my code.

```
 private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    if (column.Contains("code"))
                    {
//here i am skipping a column if it contains the string
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (column.Contains("Q"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    else if (column.Contains("M"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }
                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

Comment: ok we know what you want to do and you have posted code so thanks for that but we need to also know what is actually happening, ie what is going wrong.

Comment: i want to skip row value also if the corresponding column is skipped

Comment: my point is you haven't said what happens with your code.  Which part do you think is going wrong?  This site isn't really here for people to debug your code.  Say what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store which columns you have skipped, for example in this way:

```
List<int> skippedColumnOrdinals = new List<int>();
string[] skipWhenContains = { "code", "Q", "M" };

for (int index = 0; index < colFields.Length; index++)
{
    string column = colFields[index];
    bool skipColumn = skipWhenContains.Any(column.Contains);
    if (skipColumn)
    {
        skippedColumnOrdinals.Add(index);
        continue;
    }

    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column) { AllowDBNull = true };
    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
}

while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
{
    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields()
        .Where((field, index) => !skippedColumnOrdinals.Contains(index))
        .Select(field => field == "" ? null : field)
        .ToArray();
    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks TIm it works but i am getting "Input array is longer than the number of Columns in this table, i will find fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to import the entire content of the `.csv` file into the data table, and then simply remove the columns from the data table:

```
private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
{
    DataTable csvData = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
        {
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
            foreach (string column in colFields)
            {
                DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
            }
            while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                //Making empty value as null
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fieldData[i] == "")
                    {
                        fieldData[i] = null;
                    }
                }
                csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
            }
        }

        // get the names of the columns to remove
        var columnNamesToRemove = csvData.Columns
            .OfType<DataColumn>()
            .Where(
                c => c.Name.Contains("code") || 
                c => c.Name.Contains("Q") || 
                c => c.Name.Contains("M") 
            )
            .Select(c => c.Name);

        // remove the columns from the data table
        foreach(var name in columnNamesToRemove)
        {
            csvData.Columns.Remove(name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
    return csvData;
}
```